# max(filter()) giving an error for date range in sheets

Tags: date, sorting, google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula

I think I created a link to the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fsp7ve08GDfKClVMTgS35SgOR9u3STHewlQUy2ADJr8/edit?usp=sharing

If you looking the results tab, student B A had the same top score on 10/29/2021 and 10/15/2021. When I do a Max on the the filter it returns 0.

I have confirmed it is return a date with =isdate().  So why does the max cause the value to be 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use in C4:

```
=INDEX(SORTN(SORT({data!B2:B, data!A2:A}, data!F2:F, 0), 9^9, 2, 2, 1),,1)
```

[image]

Comment: That works... Thank you!!!!    Could you explain the logic of it all to a rookie?

Comment: @JeromeLearman sure. we take B column and A column as a range and we sort it by F column in descending order. next we use SORTN where we return all possible rows 9^9 and we use mode 2 which will group our 2nd column (A column) in ascending order 1. next we use INDEX to cut off the 2nd column and return only first one.